# table mapping by th and first td in row to populate from json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach

using php to echo json array inline i want js/jquery to populate table according to these data.

HTML table

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th data-day='2013-03-15'>15-3</th>
        <th data-day='2013-03-16'>16-3</th>
        <th data-day='2013-03-17'>17-3</th>
    </tr>    
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-time='09'>
    <td>9am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
var arr=[ 
 {"date":"2013-03-15","id":"4","time_booked":"09:00:00"},
 {"date":"2013-03-15","id":"1","time_booked":"09:10:00"},
 {"date":"2013-03-17","id":"5","time_booked":"09:30:00"}
];
$.each(arr,function(){
    console.log('id:'+this.id+'inside:'+this.date+'|'+this.time_booked);
});
</script>
```

i want to loop thro arr and according to its date and time_booked write id inside td.

for example first row will go to td with date-day='2013-03-15' and data-time='09'
so how can i do this using javascript ?

im thinking should i include data-day,data-time inside each td in tbody ? or is there a better way to do it ?

**current approach:**

include data-day inside each tr so html of tbody is

```
<tr data-time='09'>
   <td data-day='2013-03-15'></td>
   <td data-day='2013-03-16'></td>
etc..
</tr>
```

then use js

```
$.each(arr,function(){
    var rday=this.date;
    var rtime=this.time_booked;
    var sel='tr[data-hr="'+rtime.substr(0,2)+'"]';
    var dom=$(sel).find('td[data-day="'+rday+'"]').first();
    if(dom.length)dom.append(this.id);
});
```

but i have a feeling its stupid ! there must be a way to map table using x,y (table head,row head) or there is none ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the jQuery [index function](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is what you're looking for. In the code sample below, I've used it to fetch the `colIndex` for the date. In this case, it fetches all of the `th` cells within the table, and uses `.index(..)` with a selector seeking the required date. This gives the column index of the date you're seeking, and from there it's all pretty straight-forward.

```
var arr=[ 
 {"date":"2013-03-15","id":"4","time_booked":"0900"},
 {"date":"2013-03-15","id":"1","time_booked":"0910"},
 {"date":"2013-03-17","id":"5","time_booked":"0930"}
];
$.each(arr,function(){
    var cell = GetCellByDateAndTime(this.date, this.time_booked);
    $(cell).text(this.id);
});

function GetCellByDateAndTime(date, time) {
    var colIndex = $("#BookingsTable th").index($("[data-day='" + date + "']"));
    var row = $("#BookingsTable tr[data-time='" + time + "']")
    var cell = $(row).children($("td"))[colIndex];
    return cell;
}
```

And a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYR3T/).